# Capture keypress to filter elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, detection, keypress

I'm creating a `<select>` replacement using jQuery to replace it with divs and links.

Now I want to **filter** it when I start to type something with the new select open.

Like [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) does on the language selector.

Do you have any advice how do i proceed?

I started something with:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(event) {
   //...
});
```

But I capture only single keys, not the whole typed string.

---

**Important:**

- I don't have an `<input />` to detect the `keypress` or `keyup` events on it
- I prefer not to create this `<input />` since I want to use only `<div>`'s and `<a>`'s on the "new select"
- Lately I'll need to navigate on the open select with arrow keys + enter to select the option with my keyboard

Comment: FWIW, you should look at the `oninput` event, much better for detecting text input.  http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript

Comment: @Andy E - This only works with `<input />`?

Comment: @TiuTalk: it works on elements that accept input, like `<input>` and `<textarea>`.  Most devs style an input element that you can type into and attach the event to that.

Comment: @Andy E: So you suggest that I create an `<input />` to receive the keypress?

Comment: I've got some stuff working (see my answer), hopefully this is what you're after.

Comment: Problem here: If you are making a special kind of select box, you will eventually need an input to submit it if you want it to be a regular form element. It seems that making a hidden input field would solve lots of grief. see http://jsfiddle.net/pJNRB/

Comment: The google translate doesn't *filter* anything when you type, it changes selection. jQuery autocomplete filters, the example doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this by 'listening' about what is pressed on the window, and then detecting the particular letter/string pressed, search through items list and if you find it change its css properties or add a new 'selected' class i.e. (demo => http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/mC6tn/ ..try pressing whatever :) and **added** after something found press left or right btns, or enter) :

**JS**: (supposing that each element you want to find something into and select it has class 'elem')

```
var whatYouAreSearching = $('<div class="searching-string"></div>'); //just to see what string you're typing
$(document.body).append(whatYouAreSearching);

function search(what){
    what = what.toLowerCase();
    $('.elem').removeClass('selected'); //reset everything
    $.each($('.elem'),function(index,el){
        if($(el).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(what) > -1){
            $(el).addClass('selected');
            return false; //found, 'break' the each loop
        }
    });
}

var letterPressed = [];
var timeOutResetLetters = null;

$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeOutResetLetters); //clear timeout, important!
    timeOutResetLetters = setTimeout(function(){ //if 500 ms of inactivity, reset array of letters pressed and searching string
        letterPressed = []; 
        whatYouAreSearching.html('');
    },500);
    letterPressed.push(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)); //look at the comment, thanks Niclas Sahlin 
    whatYouAreSearching.html(letterPressed.join('')); //show string
    search(letterPressed.join('')); //and search string by 'joining' characters array
});
```

**EDIT** added left/right/enter keys handling

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){ //left right handling
    var currSelected = $('.elem.selected');

    if(e.keyCode == "37"){ //left, select prev
        if(currSelected.prev() && currSelected.prev().hasClass('elem')){
            currSelected.prev().addClass('selected');
            currSelected.removeClass('selected');   
        }
    }else if(e.keyCode == "39"){ //right, select next
        if(currSelected.next() && currSelected.next().hasClass('elem')){
            currSelected.next().addClass('selected');
            currSelected.removeClass('selected');   
        }
    }else if(e.keyCode == "13"){ //enter
       $('.entered').remove();
       $(document.body).append(currSelected.clone().addClass('entered'));
    }
});
```

Comment: You could use String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) if you want to catch them all without having one if statement for each.

Comment: Good solution! also I'd suggest to handle `BackSpace` key! When writing some word and making a mistake many people (including me) automatically press backspace to correct the typo, even if there is no visible <input>. In this case browser goes to the previous page :)

Comment: I don't like this solution because it's not what a user expects. Why to alter the selection when keys are pressed anywhere on the page? What about the backspace key? If it's pressed you have 2 options now (with this solution): either the browser triggers the **back** action or you catch and prevent this behavior -> which breaks the default behavior of the browser and is therefore bad.

Comment: It's the starting point to implement something similar to google translate functionality :) ..if u look there, u can press anywhere on the page.. and then, both here and there backspace is not implemented. Cheers. P.s. how would you improve this? we're here to both help and learn :)

Comment: I think the back button should also be fixed on google's site (shouldn't go back if the focus is on the custom dropdown). And still, there should be a dropdown button in your example. Typing somewhere in the page which changes the selection of a dropdown doesn't seem logical. But you're right, it's an example to get started with it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try using jQuery UI's [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Comment: That's not what I want... I really want to replace the `<select>` element

Comment: I don't have an <input /> to detect the keypress or keyup events on it

Comment: @TiuTalk: How do you replace the `<select>` element without using some kind of `<input>` element? To me, it seems like autocomplete does exactly what you want...

Comment: @TiuTalk: @Neal and @Denis are right, jQuery-UI autocomplete can replace a ``<select>`` element: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 1):

### How to do what you asked

Each time the keypress event is triggered on the document, keep a record of the character that was typed, either in a variable (accessible from the global scope or in a closure) or in an element on the page (you may choose to use `display: hidden;` if you don't want this to be visible to the user).

Then, do a pass over the elements in your dropdown and hide those that don't contain/start with the string you've built from individual keystrokes.

### What's actually recommended

Use an input element to contain the user's typed keystrokes, and let the user see the element.

### Why?

Because it's an interaction behavior users are already familiar with. If you don't use an input element, you open several new questions that are already solved with an input element:

1. *How does the user know that they can type to filter the list?* Input elements are a clear declaration to the user: "You should type here!"
2. *How does the user know what string is going to be filtered on when they press more than one key?* When I quickly type 'hu' in that Google Translate interface, 'Hungarian' is selected, as I would expect. However, what happens when I type it slowly? If it's slow enough, 'Hatian Creole' is selected, and then 'Ukranian'.
3. *What if I mistype something and want to start over?* Is there a button to press to clear it out? How long do I need to wait for the filter to clear on its own?

You *could* certainly create a new interface element that solves all of these problems, and if that's your goal, go for it, but there are preexisting standards for these sorts of things.

For one, that previously-mentioned [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) widget is really handy, and really flexible.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
var _interval;

$("#textarea/field_id").bind('keypress', function(event) {
   clearTimeout(_interval);
   _interval = setTimeout(onTimeout, 1000);
});

function onTimeout(){
   var words = $("#textarea/field_id").val().split(' ');//do what you want with the string in the field
}
```

This will capture the entire string onTimeout. Play with the timeout a little bit to get it nice and clean!

Comment: I don't have an <input /> to detect the keypress or keyup events on it

Comment: your just checking if the user is typing anywhere on a page?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var word='';
$(document).bind('keypress', function(event) {
    //UPDATE word ACCORDING TO THE CHAR, LIKE:
    if (event.charCode >=48 && event.charCode <=57) {
        ....    ....
        ....    ....
    }
    //OR
    switch(event.charCode) {
        ....    ....
        ....    ....
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created my own version of a `<select>` with `<div>` tags, check it out here.. If i understand you correctly, this is what you want..

http://jsfiddle.net/myTPC/

It also supports backspace (atleast in firefox).

Answer (score 0):

What I've tried to do is:

1) get the keypressed (only 0-9, a-z and space) and save this inside a div
2) created a LI list (you can use a div with a-elements, that's fine aswell)
3) find LI-items with the text that's being saved
4) add up/right down/left arrows to get next/previous item in the list

For now it keeps all items in the list, you can hide them aswell if you want. It's just an illustration.

// `EDIT`:

Here's a starters setup: `http://www.pendemo.nl/keyinputtest.html`
In firefox the body doesn't get automatically selected which causes that you need to click the body/webpage again before a second input is being detected. In Chrome it detects keys pressed after eachother.

// `EDIT2`:

Working in firefox. Text is now saved inside a div (you can type a string you want and see it being placed in the body).

// `EDIT3`:

Added an UL list with some items. typing some text will filter this list with items matching the typed string.

// `EDIT4`:

Only a-z and space are being used to search. Still looking for a way on how to find the backspace key. Since Chrome is adding 'history.go-1' by default. Firefox however does notice the backspace key. event.preventDefault() is not changing anything in Chrome.

// `EDIT5`:

Added up+right arrow to select next and left+down array to select previous item.

// `EDIT6`:

Upon using the enter key, the current value is alert. Ofcourse the scripts stops after the alert. But as you can see the value is available for you.

Here's the code I came up with so far:

```
var typed_string = '';

$(document).ready(function() { $('#typedtext').select(); });

$(document).bind('keypress', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if((event.which > 47 && event.which < 58) || (event.which > 96 && event.which < 123) || event.which == 32) {
        typed_string = typed_string + String.fromCharCode(event.which);
        $('#typedtext').html(typed_string);

        $('#testlist li').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
        $('#testlist li:contains('+typed_string+')').css('background-color', 'green').first().addClass('selected').css('background-color', 'red');

        $('#typedtext').select();
    }

    if(event.which == 13) {
        alert('Selected item: ' + $('.selected').html());
        $('#typedtext').select();
    }
});

$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.which == 38 || event.which == 37) {
        $('#testlist li').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
        $('#testlist li:contains('+typed_string+')').css('background-color', 'green');
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected').prev().css('background-color', 'red').addClass('selected');
    }

    if(event.which == 39 || event.which == 40) {
        $('#testlist li').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
        $('#testlist li:contains('+typed_string+')').css('background-color', 'green');
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected').next().css('background-color', 'red').addClass('selected');
    }
});

function clearInput() {
    typed_string = '';  
}
```

And I'm using this HTML:

```
Press any key to save text.<br /><br />
<div id="typedtext" style="border: 1px solid #09F; padding: 5px;"></div>

<br /><br />
Let's test to filter some items from the li. (use up/down or left/right keys to select next item)
<ul id="testlist">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>more test</li>
    <li>another item</li>
    <li>test item</li>
    <li>more item</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo bar</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>more foo</li>
</ul>
```

I think it's easy enough for you to change the HTML code to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason you don't want to use an input, is it just so if JS isn't available you can graceful fall back to the select? If so this might do what you want, I've used the select as a basis and taken the values from there although I have ended up putting an input in there.

Following on from Neal's answer, I think autocomplete is fairly similar to what you need, but if you want to display the results differently I've got a second approach in the same example that displays the filtered results.

Full example version here:
http://jsfiddle.net/R7APm/9/

Here's the JS from it:

```
$opts = $('option', '#myselect');

//Grab the text from the select (could use option values instead with .val()
var values = [];
$.each($opts, function(i, opt) {
    values.push($(opt).text());
});

$div = $('<div/>');

//Autocomplete version
$input = $('<input/>').autocomplete({
    source: values
});

//Filter in div version
$wordlist = $('<div id="wordlist"/>');
$wordlist.text(values.join(", "));

$input.keyup(function() {
    matches = $.grep(values, function(el, i) {
        if (el.toLowerCase().indexOf($input.val().toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $wordlist.text(matches.join(", "));
});

//Add new elements to wrapper div
$div.append($input);
$div.append($wordlist);

//Replace select with wrapper div
$('#replaceme').replaceWith($div);
$input.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a hidden dropdown (which i still strongly advise) i suggest following:

- Make the DIV **focusable**

  This works thanks to the "tabindex" workaround found at
  http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex
- Capture only the keystrokes on your custom dropdown, **NOT** just all on the whole document. First, it's unusual behavior. Second, how would you deal with more than 1 custom dropdown?
- Store the filter string via **jQuery's data** container

Check out the **full working demo** with a simple language dropdown at http://jsfiddle.net/aWE8b/

The demo contains:

- Custom Dropdown
- Supported keys:

  - Backspace
  - Enter
  - Escape
  - Left, Up
  - Right, Down
- 2 Modes:

  - Filter: remove unmatched items
  - Select: highlight first matched item