# f:selectItems is there a way to make the key in search work based on the last two digits of a string

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Ok I am going to try to work this correctly. I am using primefaces and specifically I am using `f:selectItems` to create a drop down of dates. Is there a way I can make it so that if someone types in the last two digits of a date it would go to that year.

I.E.

Drop down contains {2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997}

The default behavior is if i typed in 199 it would go to 1999 if I threw an 8 behind that it would go to 1998.

And I want to make it so that if someone types in 97 it would go to 1997.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: what component are you using with the f:selectItems?  h:selectOneMenu?  Or something else?

Comment: h:selectOneListbox

After doing some research last night I am having a suspension that I may have to use jquery or some java script to do this, but if you know a way I would be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using h:selectOneMenu and it's just rendering an HTML `<select>` element, you could possibly do something by hijacking the keypress event.  But it seems like a bad idea to break the default browser `<select>` behavior.

Similar answer / opinion expressed here:

[Capture keypress to filter elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939047/capture-keypress-to-filter-elements)